# C# working with singleton from two different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

I am using the singleton pattern in a wpf app, but having doubts about how to make it work with multiple threads.

I have a class called Monitor which maintains a list of "settings" to watch, for different "devices". Outline shown below.

On my main thread I am doing 
Monitor.getMonitor.register(watchlist) or Monitor.getMonitor.unregister(...) depending on the user input and I have a DispatchTimer running every 200ms that does a 
Monitor.getMonitor.update()

```
public class Monitor
{
    private Hashtable Master; //key=device, value=list of settings to watch
    private static Monitor instance = new Monitor();
    private Monitor() {}
    public static Monitor getMonitor() 
    {
        return instance;
    }
    public void register(watchlist){...}
    public void unregister(...){...}
    public void update(){...}

}
```

register()/unregister() perform add/remove to the hastable.
update() is only reading stuff out of the hashtable.

Depending on the number of devices and settings, update() is going to be iterating over the hastable and it contents, getting the latest values.
The main thread maybe calling register and unregister quite often and I want the gui to stay responsive. Whats a good way to do this?

Do I lock the hashtable, around add/remove and iterate, OR just surrond the iteration part in update with a try catch (ala gracefully fail) to catch any weird state the hashtable might get into(no locking) or is there some better way to do this (if update fails no prob..its going to be running in 200ms again anyway).

Not very sure about what is going on, cause the code as is hasnt really shown any problems which itself is making me a bit uneasy cause it just seems wrong. Thanks for any suggestions...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See my [article on singleton implementations](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/singleton.html) to make the singleton fetching itself threadsafe.

Yes, you'll need to lock when you modify *or* iterate over the hashtable. You could use a [`ReaderWriterLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) (or preferrably [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) in .NET 3.5) to allow multiple readers at a time. If you need to do a lot of work while you're iterating, you could always lock, take a copy, unlock, and then work on the copy - so long as the work doesn't mind the copy being slightly stale.

(If you're using .NET 2.0+, I'd suggest using the generic collections such as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead of `Hashtable`. I'd also suggest you rename your methods in line with .NET conventions. That code's got a distinct Java accent at the moment ;)

Comment: Nice mention of ReaderWriterLockSlim.  Hadn't seen that one yet.

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thanks for the response. Just to try and understand this a bit better could you please elaborate on that italicized 'or'?
I am using 3.5, And thanks for the reminder on .NET conventions, this is kind of a one man project so been slacking off in that dept.

Comment: @Jon Nice article on Singletons too. I was aware of the Java double check locking issue, but wasn't aware of creating a Singleton with a nested class- is that definitely the best technique? CLR via C# has a much simpler technique that I believe achieves the same thing.

Comment: @Jon- I've just read the 4th method again. It seems your best technique assumes other statics members within the class. Having those seems highly unlikely though?

Comment: @Klerk: you will need to take a reader lock when reading from the hashtable; you can have several such locks at the same time. You cannot get a writer lock if there is an active reader lock, and the other way around. There can be only one active writer lock at a time. In that way you can guarantee that the data does not change while you are reading from it, and that only thread at a time can write to the hash table.

Comment: The 4th version doesn't use a nested class. The 5th does. The 4th version is only less lazy than it can be in the face of other statics, yes - normally not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should lock each operation:

```
 public class Monitor
 {
     private Hashtable Master; //key=device, value=list of settings to watch
     ...
     private object tableLock = new object();
     public void register(watchlist) 
     {
         lock(tableLock) {
             // do stuff
         }
     }
 }
```

You shouldn't consider using a try/catch block - exceptions shouldn't be considered as a "normal" situation, and you might end up with a corrupted object state without any exception.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows are there?  Unless the update() loop takes a long time to do the iterations, I'd probably lock.  If the main thread is potentially doing a lot of register/unregister calls, then update might fail repeatedly -- if it fails for 20 or 30 consecutive calls, is that a problem?

That code looks ok to me.  I'd probably make the class sealed.  I'd also use a typed dictionary vs. a Hashtable.

Comment: Update time generally isnt much but there is an ocassional chance that there is a big delay as there is a network request involved. And update failures are acceptable. But you have raised another issue, if the update takes longer than the 200ms I have no idea what is going to happen if a second call to update happens when the first one hasnt completed. <sigh>

Comment: @Klerk, the simplest solution would be to have a guard check at the top of the loop method that will immediately execute if it hasn't completed the previous call. This means you could end up skipping intervals, but if that's ok, then it's fast, easy, and foolproof.